# How to prevent a site from checking for my manifest file?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a popular Chrome extension that is being targeted by a specific site and they are messing with our extensions functionality and telling visitors to uninstall our extension. They are detecting we are running in the browser by checking for our manifest file via looking for the URL `chrome-extension://our-app-id/manifest.json`. Is there anyway I can prevent this?

I tried using `content-security-policy` but that seems to only help with cross-scripting. If not seems like a security hole on google's part; I don't want sites knowing what extensions I am running in my browser.

Answer (score 2):

Manifest version 2 that is tentatively scheduled for version 18 should [fix this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/1B5-t0_V3nc/z8fjrYkSip4J).

> [...] today, all the resources inside your extension (e.g., images)
>   are visible to web pages.  We're changing the default to "not visible"
>   and then adding a manifest attribute to let you whitelist the
>   resources that you want to be accessible to web pages.

Comment: i just ran Canary v19.0.1 and it didn't seem to be not visible by default.. any word on what the manifest property name would be?

Comment: i know that.. i mean what is the attribute for whitelisting the sources which can see inside your extension

Comment: It should be some combination of [CSP](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/contentSecurityPolicy.html)